# SQL script to insert new records

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have one table whereas there are 5 millions records available and each day that records add by 20000 to 50000. I want to create script where I can keep old records and add all new records each day in existing table. I am using SQL server 2008R2.

```
+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|    Date    | Activity | COnversions | Impressions |
+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
| 03/03/2014 | Book     | 52          | 1000        |
| 03/03/2014 | Mobile   | 100         | 5000        |
| 03/04/2014 | Book     | 60          | 4500        |
| 03/04/2014 | Mobile   | 40          | 6000        |
| 03/05/2014 | yahoo    | 58          | 2000        |
| 03/05/2014 | MSN      | 46          | 1500        |
+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

The above is exisiting table for example.

```
New data:
+------------+--------+-----+-------+
| 03/03/2014 | Book   | 52  | 1000  |
| 03/03/2014 | Mobile | 100 | 5000  |
| 03/04/2014 | Book   | 60  | 4500  |
| 03/04/2014 | Mobile | 40  | 6000  |
| 03/05/2014 | yahoo  | 58  | 2000  |
| 03/05/2014 | MSN    | 46  | 1500  |
| 03/06/2014 | Book   | 93  | 7000  |
| 03/06/2014 | Google | 97  | 15000 |
+------------+--------+-----+-------+
```

Now If you notice that date 03/06/2014 is new records in the raw table and I want to insert only this new records to the above fact table whereas I am inserting all data from different tables with the help of **STORE PROCEDURE.**

Questions: How can I make this process (SQL script) automated through SQL server Management Studio? Whereas I can input all new records automatically and prevent existing data to get double.

I am planning to write this script and want to make this process automate via **SSIS and SQL server Agent**, but don't have much clue about **SQL store procedure**. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a primary key column in the table ??

Comment: No I dont have any primary key in column. That is why it's getting  me a tough time Otherwise i would have tried Begin Transaction with IF Exist statement. But without Primary key it's become complicated for me because I am not a expert level person in SQL.

Comment: Don't know why you want to use SSIS. I would just use a [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement and omit the WHEN MATCHED clause

Comment: @ConardFrix: No its not mandatory that i want to use SSIS. it's just idea of me that can i use SSIS or not. However, as you said MERGE state how would you use and omit when matched clause. How can i do that can you please elaborate. Actually, I am not looking for particular answer, I am looking for correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

So it appears that Date and Activity is a candidate composite key. Using that you could construct the following

```
MERGE CurrentData as target
USING NewData as source
ON (target.date = source.date
    and target.activity = source.activity)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (Date, Activity, Conversions, Impressions) 
VALUES (source.Date, source.Activity, source.Conversions, source.Impressions);
```

Given the number of records you have I'd make sure that you have indexes on `{date, activity}` on both tables

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0f5c/15)

Note: CurrentData and NewData need to be replaced with the actual table names

Comment: @Conard Frix: Thanks a lot for this solution, however the number of records are 8.8 millions till now and will be add 200K to 500K on daily basis. I will try your script and lets see and whatever output come then definitely i will let you know.

Comment: @ConardFrix : thank you so much both of you for your health because I have tried your both version of solution and it did work perfectly for short table. Now i am going to write the same script for fact table whereas all millions of records are available and will insert on daily basis. If i will have questions then will ask you for sure. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Philip: thank you so much both of you for your health because I have tried your both version of solution and it did work perfectly for short table. Now i am going to write the same script for fact table whereas all millions of records are available and will insert on daily basis. If i will have questions then will ask you for sure. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user3299024 Philp likely didn't see this comment. See [How do comment `@replies work`?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/148672) for why.

Comment: @Conrad, thanks for pointing that out. I find SELECT EXCEPT good for "bulk processing", such as when you have to hit all columns in a table, and MERGE is the power tool to pull out when things get seriously complex.

Answer (score 2):

Something based on the following should work:

```
INSERT MyTable (Date, Activity, Conversions, Impressions)
 select Date, Activity, Conversions, Impressions
  from RawTable
 except select Date, Activity, Conversions, Impressions
  from MyTable
```

This will:

- select all rows from your "raw" table
- remove any rows that are (already) matched in the target table
- insert the remaining "new" rows into the target table

The downside is ugly table scans on multi-million row tables, but without indexes or careful planning there's not much you can do about that.

Turning this into a basic stored procedure is fairly simple:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LoadNewData
AS

    INSERT MyTable (Date, Activity, Conversions, Impressions)
     select Date, Activity, Conversions, Impressions
      from RawTable
     except select Date, Activity, Conversions, Impressions
      from MyTable

GO
```

Lots of bells and whistles are possible here (Nocount, error handling, return codes, activity logging, etc. etc.), much depends on what you want or need to do above and beyond loading data.

As for automating it through SSMS, you want to look into SQL Agent jobs. This is a long and somewhat complex subject, and a quick google search should turn up dozens of competent articles on the subject.

Comment: Thank you philip for your solution and I will also use your solution and will let you know whatever output come. However, I know how to set the job in SQL server agent because I did that before, but this inserting new records each day I am doing first time. Therefore, it's getting hard time for me. Thanks a lot again Philip.

Comment: I think [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184241/sql-script-to-insert-new-records/22185246?#comment33713746_22185246) on my answer was meant for you. Nice use of `Except` by the way